# Adding up in dict

Tags: python

```
series[1][2] = 3
val = 7
```

How can I add `val` to `series[1][2]` so that `series[1][2]` becomes 10?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
series[1][2] += val
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with:

```
series[1][2]+=val
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store the values in a different variable then you can do like:

```
x = (series[1][2] + val)
```

otherwise
  `series[1][2] += val`
will do your work fine if you want to append after summing.